# Asking which answer is regarded as duplicate

Tags: support, deleted-answers

ChrisF deletes one of my answers (Deleted on [Parallel processes: appending outputs to an array in a zsh script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544688/parallel-processes-appending-outputs-to-an-array-in-a-zsh-script/51650945)) with the reason:

> Please don't post duplicate answers. If the questions are the same answer one and vote to close the other(s) as duplicate. If they're not the same then tailor your answer to the specifics of each question.

I have searched for which answer may be a duplicate without being able to find it. How do I ask @ChrisF for clarification on which answer he believes is a duplicate?

**Summary**

BiBi posts a question ([Parallel processes: appending outputs to an array in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544071/)) and tags it both `zsh` and `bash`. Charles Duffy points out that the differences between Zsh and Bash in this area are so big, that BiBi should make it two questions: One for Zsh and one for Bash. BiBi does so ([Parallel processes: appending outputs to an array in a zsh script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544688/)).

`parset` is developed to solve this exact problem. There is a version for Zsh and a different version for Bash (but there is no version for, say, Csh). The code is different between `zsh` and `bash`. The API is the same.

Non-trivial differences include:

```
$ diff env_parallel.bash env_parallel.zsh
--- env_parallel.bash   2018-07-18 17:48:08.000000000 +0200
+++ env_parallel.zsh    2018-07-18 18:26:34.000000000 +0200
@@ -26,42 +26,35 @@
     _names_of_ALIASES() {
-       compgen -a
+       print -l ${(k)aliases}
     }
     _bodies_of_ALIASES() {
        local _i
-       for _i in $@; do
-           if [ $(alias $_i | wc -l) == 1 ] ; then
-               true Alias is a single line. Good.
-           else
-               _warning_PAR "Alias '$_i' contains newline."
-               _warning_PAR "Make sure the command has at least one newline after '$_i'."
-               _warning_PAR "See BUGS in 'man env_parallel'."
-           fi
+       for _i ($@); do
+               echo 'alias '"$(alias $_i)"
        done
-       alias "$@"
     }
     _names_of_FUNCTIONS() {
-       compgen -A function
+       print -l ${(k)functions}
     }
     _bodies_of_FUNCTIONS() {
        typeset -f "$@"
     }
     _names_of_VARIABLES() {
-       compgen -A variable
+       print -l ${(k)parameters}
     }
     _bodies_of_VARIABLES() {
        typeset -p "$@"
     }
     _ignore_HARDCODED() {
        # These names cannot be detected
-       echo '(_|TIMEOUT|GROUPS|FUNCNAME|DIRSTACK|PIPESTATUS|USERNAME|BASH_[A-Z_]+)'
+       echo '([-\?\#\!\$\*\@\_0]|zsh_eval_context|ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT|LINENO|IFS|commands|functions|options|aliases|EUID|EGID|UID|GID|dis_patchars|patchars|terminfo|galiases|keymaps|parameters|jobdirs|dirstack|functrace|funcsourcetrace|zsh_scheduled_events|dis_aliases|dis_reswords|dis_saliases|modules|reswords|saliases|widgets|userdirs|historywords|nameddirs|termcap|dis_builtins|dis_functions|jobtexts|funcfiletrace|dis_galiases|builtins|history|jobstates|funcstack)'
     }
     _ignore_READONLY() {
-       readonly | perl -e '@r = map {
+       typeset -pr | perl -e '@r = map {
                 chomp;
                 # sh on UnixWare: readonly TIMEOUT
                # ash: readonly var='val'
@@ -123,14 +116,6 @@
             /^'"$_ignore_HARD"'$/ and next;
             print;'
     }
-    _prefix_PARALLEL_ENV() {
-        shopt 2>/dev/null |
-        perl -pe 's:\s+off:;: and s/^/shopt -u /;
-                  s:\s+on:;: and s/^/shopt -s /;
-                  s:;$:&>/dev/null;:';
-        echo 'shopt -s expand_aliases &>/dev/null';
-    }
-
     _get_ignored_VARS() {
         perl -e '
             for(@ARGV){
@@ -263,14 +244,10 @@
     PARALLEL_ENV="`
-        _prefix_PARALLEL_ENV
-        $_list_alias_BODIES;
-        $_list_function_BODIES;
-        $_list_variable_VALUES;
+        eval $_list_alias_BODIES;
+        eval $_list_function_BODIES;
+        eval $_list_variable_VALUES;
     `"
     export PARALLEL_ENV
     unset _list_alias_BODIES
@@ -350,21 +327,21 @@
     if perl -e 'exit not grep /,| /, @ARGV' "$_parset_name" ; then
        # $_parset_name contains , or space
        # Split on , or space to get the names
-       eval "$(
+       eval "`
            # Compute results into files
            $_parset_parallel_prg --files -k "$@" |
-               # var1=`cat tmpfile1; rm tmpfile1`
-               # var2=`cat tmpfile2; rm tmpfile2`
-               parallel -q echo {2}='`cat {1}; rm {1}`' :::: - :::+ $(
+               # var1= cat tmpfile1; rm tmpfile1
+               # var2= cat tmpfile2; rm tmpfile2
+               parallel -q echo {2}='\`cat {1}; rm {1}\`' :::: - :::+ \`
                    echo "$_parset_name" |
                        perl -pe 's/,/ /g'
-                        )
-           )"
+                        \`
+           `"
```

I answer both questions. The difference in the answers is the library to include:

```
. `which env_parallel.bash`
```

And:

```
. `which env_parallel.zsh`
```

ChrisF deletes the `zsh` answer with the reason that it is a duplicate.

I raise this issue, because I think it is an error, and I want to discuss the issue with ChrisF, and thus need a way to communicate with him. (It is still unclear to me whether there is a better way to communicate with the moderator – if there is, please post an answer).

When shown what answers he believes are the same, I am convinced this is an error: He (or the computer) simply missed the difference in names or the point that the two libraries run different code. The Zsh-code will not work in Bash and vice versa. So the Zsh-answer would be wrong on the Bash-question and the Bash-answer would be wrong on the Zsh-question.

It is clear, that the answers (just like the questions) are similar, but have subtle differences due to being tailored for Zsh and Bash. The answers are no more duplicates than the questions are duplicates.

I could instead have included the relevant parts of the libraries which I believe everyone would agree is so different that they are clearly not duplicates (see the differences above). I did not do this, because I think it is valuable to learn you do not need to remember two different ways to solve the problem, but instead learn that there are two libraries designed to have the same API that solves the problem for you.

**Why are the two answers valuable to SO?**

By deleting the answer on the `zsh` question we make it harder for people to find out that there exists a library for Zsh, that solves this issue.

Even if you knew of `parset` for Bash, it would not help you, because it is *not* safe in general to assume that it exists for Zsh, too. For example `parset` does not exist for Csh even though `env_parallel.csh` does exist.

Comment: [Here you go.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544071/parallel-processes-appending-outputs-to-an-array-in-a-bash-script/51650970#51650970) Your answer was an exact copy of an existing answer.

Comment: @jpp but that is not a duplicate. One is for bash the other is for zsh. You can see bash is replaced with zsh. The two questions are for bash and zsh repectively. Just as the questions are very similar in wording it can hardly be surprising that the answers will be similar, too.

Comment: That's not the point. If you see yourself copy-pasting an answer, make sure you differentiate it, SO answers should *add value*. There's a point to this. You could have commented with a link to your existing answer, or added some explanation as to why it is appropriate here too, or explain how it works.

Comment: @jpp But I *did* differentiate it: zsh for the zsh question. bash for the bash question. They are not duplicates. At most you can call them very similar. And they *do* add value, as it is non-obvious that there is a parset for bash and another one for zsh.

Comment: Do consider editing your meta post.  Pretending that you don't know that you posted the exact same code twice and had to search does not exactly help you.  You can still defend it, the OP made the duplicate.

Comment: @HansPassant But the code is factually NOT the same: One works in Zsh, the other does not. One works in Bash, the other does not. It is simply untrue to say the code is the same. And that is the reason why I would like to ask ChrisF for clarification. Did he test the code? Or did he simply assume that replacing zsh with bash gives the same code (even though it is clearly two very different files)? Or was there another reason why he mistook the posts to be duplicates? Maybe he simply overlooked the fact that one uses Zsh while the other uses Bash?

Comment: Maybe you should have waited to get an answer to this question before reposting the deleted answer.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have posted a new answer based on the old one with a note to the moderation specifically addressing that this is not a duplicate because it uses different file for zsh and not bash. This moderation note is not in the original deleted answer (Maybe you forgot to look at the edit history and you simply assumed the newest deleted answer would be the original one? - It is not). None of the comments so far seem to get us any closer on how to ask a moderator for clarification.

Comment: No, I did see that. I just don't think adding a note to moderators means it isn't reposting the same answer. I guess it depends on your interpretation of "same", and apparently we have a difference of opinion there. Anyway, I agree my comment wasn't addressing your original question. Just a related observation.

Comment: @OleTange Notes adressing moderators don't belong in an answer, btw.

Comment: @ModusTollens ... which brings us full circle back to the original question: How to ask a moderator for clarification?

Comment: honestly it's a perfect duplicate .. so If i follow your logic I can answer using the exact same code a question about C and another one about C++? I am also reading about the difference between both (http://stackabuse.com/zsh-vs-bash/) and both are base on sheel scripting

Comment: even in your answer you said it `parset is supported in Bash/Ksh/Zsh (including arrays)` ... so this means that the function can be used the same with zsh or bash and the only difference in the code is the exension of the env file ... I have a little experience with bash but it's more than clear that both code and answer are exactly the same

Comment: Let us just get rid of that misconception once and for all: The code is NOT exactly the same. If you still think so, I encourage you to verify that claim by comparing the actual files `env_parallel.bash` and `env_parallel.zsh`: Two different implementations tailored for the specific shells. You can verify that they will not work correctly in the other shell by using the wrong library and running: `env_parset a echo ::: b`

Comment: `parset` is supported in both Bash and Zsh, but that does not imply that the only difference is the file extension. `parset` has by design the same API in both shells. Maybe it is last part that confuses people: The API is the same, but the code in the library is different.

Comment: All the argument you are using are against you. By saying : *The API is the same in both* you agree that your code is the same. Who care about the implementation? all the implemenation aren't the same between version. `printf` the most common function in C has a multiple implementation among different version and different system but it the same function used by everyone in this planet ... even if later you will use `cout` of C++ it will remain the same because the logic is *print something on the screen* --> replacing cout with printf will not make the code different

Comment: @TemaniAfif “Who care[s] about the implementation?” The user. He cares that there _is_ an implementation, and without the `zsh`-answer you still have to justify how the user would find out that there is a `parset` for `zsh` when there is none for `csh`. Please explain how the user would do that without the `zsh` answer.

Answer (score 12):

You posted exactly the same answer to two questions. This was automatically flagged by the system. If the same answer applies to more than one question then that's a good sign that the questions are duplicates. You didn't find the duplicate answer because I'd deleted it so it now longer shows up in your profile. You'd find it if you browsed to the question.

It they're duplicates then you should be answering one and voting to close the other as a duplicate.

If they're not duplicates then you should be tailoring each answer to the specifics of each question, which should be more than just changing the extension of a filename.

Comment: I think he's not convinced that both are the same even if it's trivial... that's the issue.

Comment: @Temani which is why I hopefully stressed that the system had detected the duplicate.

Comment: Can we start by agreeing that the answers differ in that one says 'zsh' where the other says 'bash'? And can we then agree that they run different code: One is tailored for zsh, the other does not work in zsh. One is tailored for bash, the other does not work in bash. Given that they are written in different languages: Can we therefore agree that they clearly are NOT exactly the same answer - even if the computer may says so?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The tailoring is in which library to load (Either `env_parallel.zsh` or `env_parallel.bash`, and these files differ by more than trivial changes. If you still believe the change is trivial, go look at the actual files: they differ by around 10 non-trivial lines). The tailoring is not in the API, which by design is the same for both libraries.

Comment: Just to be clear: The questions are also not duplicates: One is for bash, the other is for zsh. The goal is the same, but for two different languages. It will therefore not make sense to vote to close either of them.

Comment: @Ole if the answers differed the the **system** wouldn't have flagged them as duplicates. Make sure the answer has been tailored *before* you post it.

Comment: @OleTange Honestly I don't know what to say, I am impressed how you still persist on saying the same ... so changing the extension of a file simply because you changed the environnement is enough for you to say that  they are not the same? I will not start an argue-fight with you but simply take a look around, you got -20 for the question, this answer got +8, I suppose the meta effect gave you -2 for your answer --> Considering this, I think there is an issue. You cannot convince me that you are true and we all are wrong.

Comment: @ChrisF Maybe the system has an error? It is not unheard of for software to have bugs. But why trust the machine, when you can check for yourself: Look at the two answer. Does one include the library `env_parallel.zsh` and does the other one include `env_parallel.bash`? If so can we then agree that they are include different libraries? And looking at the files included, can we then agree that there are non-trivial differences in the libraries?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am not sure how to explain this to you. So can you please take out a file comparison tool and do a diff on the two files in question (`env_parallel.bash` and `env_parallel.zsh`) and report back. Are they different? Are the differences non-trivial? Can we now agree that the file extension is the least of the differences?

Comment: @OleTange come one :) so If in a code, I use the same image, one with PNG extension and the other one with a JPG extension then my code is different? ... we don't talk about *binary* or *text* difference, it's about logic, knowledge, algorithm, etc ... Both your answer use the same logic, the same algorithm, the same function, you simply changed the script environment from zsh to bash and both are shell ... You are also talking about files that we don't even need to know what there is inside. They are handled by the system and we simply need to run a *blind*  command at the start to call them.

Comment: @OleTange and what would you say about this : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371710/user-actively-repeating-the-same-answer-mod-flag-already-used ... I was debating with moderator because the code wasn't the same but the logic was the same and at the end The community agreed with me and I got the answers deleted. But in your case, it's the system that detects the duplicate and it's more than trivial that the code is the same which implies that the logic is also the same, we don't even need knowledge within that particular area to notice this.

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you know of a library that supports PNG and you need the same function, but for JPG, then yes: I think it is valuable information to know that there is a different library that will solve the problem for JPG – even if the API is the same and even if the name of the library is very similar to the one you use. The reason for this is that it is not obvious whether there is also a library that supports the function for TIFF (or other formats). Personally I would find it valuable information even if the exactly the same library could be used for all three of them.